# how to get the response json data from network call in XHR using Python selenium web driver chorme

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need the JSON data from network calls in the python selenium webdriver or even one specific URL response JSON data from the network call.

Here is the image of sample data I want

[image]

exactly i want "Mobikwik Offer" from the JSON response from the network call.

Could any one help me on this, Also suggest the alternate options to get this data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `pre` element and get its text, then load it via `json.loads():`

```
import json 

pre = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
data = json.loads(pre)
print(data)
```

For more info please visit

http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-web-driver-menu/selenium-test-automation-with-python/235-how-to-test-json-with-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the headers for request url. Use that api url with requests lib. Something like:

```
import requests, json

url = *url here*
response = requests.get(url)
json_value = response.json()
alt = json_value['alt']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the Request URL with `requests`. Selenium is unnecessary.

```
import requests

url = 'https://s0.dominosindia.in/s0-olo-api-bucket/v1/widgetcontent/brandOffers'
find = 'Mobikwik Offer'  

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
data = response['data']

for ele in data:
    if ele['alt'] == find:
        id_key = ele['id']
        imageUrl = ele['imageUrl']
        alt = ele['alt']

        print (ele)
```

Comment: I provided this site for a sample. I need to do the same as extract from network calls, as my actual site is protected with dynamic authentication inputs. If this could be done with selenium would be great.